# Get max one result of each value in a column

Tags: sql, informix

I'm working with a Informix DB and with a table like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
a    a    a
b    a    c
c    b    a
d    c    d
```

Is it possible from the SQL statement to just display ONE of the first 2 rows by just specify only unique results (values can be anything). I only want one result from col2 with the same value and I don't mind which one of the lines being retrieved.

I hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a tie-breaking column (a single-column primary key), you could use something like this

```
select t.*
from (
    select col2, min(pk_id) pk_id
    from tbl
    group by col2
) x, tbl t
where t.col2=x.col2 and t.pk_id=x.pk_id
```

Comment: Brilliant and thanks for a quick reply! Just a short question.. I could easily do this in my code getting the result set and from a performance point of view, is that SQL "heavy" for the DB?

Comment: @StefanE Not at all, that is what DBs are for, to perform SET-based operations and very quickly.